# How to show uploaded files in uploadcare?

Tags: php, image, file, cdn, uploadcare

I'm using [uploadcare.com](https://uploadcare.com) to store my images and files. I just started using it now. I was just wondering that how can i display the uploaded files in a web page. I looked through the [documentation](https://uploadcare.com/documentation/) too. But didn't get anything to start with?

Is there anyone who have used it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://uploadcare.com/documentation/), all images are available via CDN URL (this URL is returned by widget, it's up to you to save it). To add an image to your page just add an `img` tag:

`<img src="http://www.ucarecdn.com/5651bbb6-c599-44bd-9c63-1db5e67db6ad/" />`